# Jquery getScript is not Working?

Tags: jquery

Dear Friends i used jquery for drop down menu with scroll bar js plugin.
 when i load script like.

```
<script src="js/jquery.dd.js"></script>
```

it working properly.

but when i try to load is not working.

```
$.getScript( "js/jquery.dd.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

i try to load js file to runtime but is not working. please help.
Thanks.

Comment: You must surely be getting some kind of error. (Not my dv)

Comment: I would imagine the issue is because the `dd.js` script is designed to run on the document.ready event, yet this has already happened before you call `getScript`, therefore the plugin is never instatiated.

Comment: Please define "not working". What do you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes no i not got any error file load successfully but combo box is not design with scroll. it lokk like simple.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Actually if you bind to document.ready after it's already ready, then the callback is just ran immediately.

Comment: @RocketHazmat fair enough then. I can't say I've ever nested ready handlers to try it :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yeah, there's actually a "gotcha" waiting there: If you pass a ready handler to jQuery but the ready event has already fired, the handler is called *synchronously* (whereas if the event hasn't already run, naturally the call is asynchronous). So depending on what you're doing after you register the handler... I reported it as a bug, but while they agreed it wasn't ideal, they decided not to change it. :-)

Comment: When you call the plugin `$('.selector').dd()`? You should call it inside the callback (after your console.log)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May your **Scripts** are not **sequenced** try this,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.getScript( "js/jquery.dd.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
            console.log( data ); // Data returned
            console.log( textStatus ); // Success
            console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
            console.log( "Load was performed." );
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/AT3Af/) may help you

Comment: @Developer -- Please give a description of what happens, "not working" is the single least informative statement :\

Comment: i have jquery plugin to design my combo box with scroll. but when i load script using getScript is load successfully but my combo box is not design with scroll it look like simple.

Comment: how to add more js plugin files with/using $.getscript() and how to initialize it?